# How to resolve this "PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call..."

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess

I've been struggling with a call to an Oracle database for over a day now.  I have no access to the database other than programmatically, although a DBA was able to give me the following:

```
desc appowner.member_data_package

PROCEDURE UPDATE_NOTES_V001
Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
TAU_UID_IN                     VARCHAR2                IN
INCOMING_FUNC_IN               VARCHAR2                IN
INCOMING_TEXT_IN               VARCHAR2                IN
SYS_SOURCE_IN                  VARCHAR2                IN
USER_ID_IN                     VARCHAR2                IN
O_STATUS                       VARCHAR2                OUT
```

My code looks like this:

```
using (var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand
    {
        Connection = connection,
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        CommandText = "appowner.MEMBER_DATA_PACKAGE.UPDATE_NOTES_V001",
        BindByName = true
    };

    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("O_STATUS", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue));
    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("TAU_UID_IN", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = "7400";
    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("INCOMING_FUNC_IN", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = "PROVCOUNT";
    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("INCOMING_TEXT_IN", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = "Pypestream testing.";
    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("SYS_SOURCE_IN", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = "CRM";
    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("USER_ID_IN", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = "jac";

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine($"Insert output value is '{command.Parameters["O_STATUS"].Value.ToString()}'");

}
```

The error I get when I run this is:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'UPDATE_NOTES_V001'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

As far as I can tell I *do* have the right number and types of arguments, but if somebody wiser than me in the ways of Oracle (which, basically, is anyone) can point out where I messed up that would be awesome.

If that part looks right and the error is a red herring of some sort, what else can I look at?  Is there some other way to call this procedure?  Keep in mind I have no tools other than Visual Studio 2017.  I cannot download any helpful extensions.  I have no direct access to the database other than an email to the DBA.

I also confess that I could be on a completely wrong tack here.  I'm totally guessing the code to insert values into the Oracle database would look like this based on some examples I've seen here and around the 'net.  Any advice to tackle this would be helpful.

Comment: if you are passing Parameters in Oracle, then you need to pass them in the exact order that is declared in your Oracle Stored Procedure. or changed this `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` to `ParameterDirection.OutPut` can you show the exact Sql Statement..

Comment: can you show the full procedure along with the SQL where are you assigning the value to be returned.. when doing INSERTS one would expect a return value to be of type INT in Oracle Number, and INT are different one is translated as a `decimal` while the other one is an INTEGER ...I had fixed an similar Issue like this actually lastnight

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot show the procedure.  Literally all I have to go on is the desc I provided above.  @MethodMan, I would have thought the proc would return something other than a varchar2 as well, but unless the desc is inaccurate somehow it seems to be text.

Comment: without seeing your SELECT Statement and how you are assigning your variable into the Return Variable / OUT Param, then you are pretty much on your own.. also I would think that the procedure would take at least one  out param.. but I can't tell because you are not really showing the procedure signature..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to the Oracle procedures needs to match the type and order of the parameters of the called procedure.  Also, a parameter that returns a value is an OutPut parameter.  Your code does not match the parameters of the called procedure, hence the error.  Change it to:

```
using (var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
connection.Open();

OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand
{
    Connection = connection,
    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
    CommandText = "appowner.MEMBER_DATA_PACKAGE.UPDATE_NOTES_V001",
    BindByName = true
};

command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("TAU_UID_IN", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = "7400";
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("INCOMING_FUNC_IN", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = "PROVCOUNT";
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("INCOMING_TEXT_IN", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = "Pypestream testing.";
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("SYS_SOURCE_IN", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = "CRM";
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("USER_ID_IN", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = "jac";
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("O_STATUS", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.OutPut));

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
Console.WriteLine($"Insert output value is '{command.Parameters["O_STATUS"].Value.ToString()}'");

}
```

Comment: For some reason "ReturnValue" struck me as being the same at "OutPut".  I wasn't concerned about the order because I thought the "BindByName" would overrule something like that (not sure why they even need the name if I placing them in the right order).  However, the tips here solved my problem.

Comment: The name portion of the `command.Parameters.Add` allows you to call that specific parameter by name.  It's not something I have used, but it's there if you need to use it.

Comment: @PrescottChartier I have theo following mycursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR , what is the OracleDbType equivalent ?

Comment: @PrescottChartier RefCursor is the solution